# Upload Image file in Server error

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I am trying to upload a image from HTML to PHP. I am facing error. Could some one help me to solved the issue. Below is the error message.

```
Error Messgae:
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The
script whose uid is 0 is not allowed to access
/var/www/smart/JSON/taskfinished/666 owned by uid 33 in
/var/www/smart/JSON/taskimageupload.php on line 57"
```

I am sure the error is not in my PHP Script because it is working fine in shared server and many other servers. But when I run the script in my dedicated server I am facing the above error.

I change the file permission to 0777 so that every one have permission to use it but still the  problem resides the same.

I feel some thing has to be change in the server. So some one tell me what exactly I am missing in my server.

Comment: You need to have safe mode turned off in your php.ini file ,Enabling safe_mode is not needed if other reasonable security precautions are followed. Using safe_mode for web site security is a poor compromise in a bad situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue with the following configuration to the server.

Find your `php.ini` file in server in my case it is in `usr/Apache/bin`

and find out the below code:

```
; Safe Mode
; http://php.net/safe-mode
safe_mode = On
```

change the above code to below

```
; Safe Mode
; http://php.net/safe-mode
safe_mode = Off
```

It simply means that you are turning of the SAFE MODE, It don't mean that your Server is no longer safe, But if the basic security are perfect in your server then no matter what you do with the above line. :)

Hope this help some one!